# KendoChart stack/group sorting in different browsers

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm having trouble with my Kendo UI Chart, where I want data stacked and grouped.
The problem is that when I group the data, the bars is no longer chronological (in different browsers, more on that later).

Can someone please help?

I've set up an [example in Telerik Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OxAbudEB).

This seems to work, except in Chrome.

However, this is just a part of the code. The original code is angularjs-based, and with a whole lot of code to process settings to create options. That however, works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE and Edge.

Can someone point me in a direction to solve this in "all" browsers?

Answer (score 0):

So, my co-worker Martin pointed me to this solution:

```
dataBound: function(e) {
var axis = e.sender.options.categoryAxis;
axis.categories = axis.categories.sort();
```

}
Works great in this minimized example, but didn't work in my more complex code.
Turns out that my code removes the categoryField from the series in some cases. With the categoryField still there, the sorting works.

Now I need to figure out why and when the categoryField must be removed, but that's not a question for Stack Overflow.